# Issues with file rights in CentOS

Tags: centos, chmod, chown, permissions

May someone explain me how to manage rights correctly pls? I have a file with these rights:

```
8 -rw-r--r--+ 1 sntecard  sntecard    4669 Sep 18 12:34 index.php
```

I am accessing this folder by user myuser and trying to modify it. Sure, I can't. Ok, I am adding group write rights and add myself to sntecard group (being a root):

```
usermod -a -G sntecard myuser

chmod g+w index.php
```

Let's check rights: (ls -ls)

```
8 -rw-rw-r--+ 1 sntecard  sntecard    4669 Sep 18 12:34 index.php
```

Now let's check I am in a group: (grep sntecard /etc/group)

```
sntecard:x:503:sntecard,myuser
```

Awesome, I am in a group and now SHOULD TO have rights! But NO. I can't write this file. Impossible thru sFTP and impossible ever thru nano index.php. Access error when writting a file.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. What is that "+" at the end of rights line actually means?

Comment: You have to login again to make group membership effective.

Comment: @Tometzky I've tried that. I am logging in new SSH session and trying to write file from there. Same effect.

Comment: getfacl index.php to answer "+" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer by myself. "+" means alternative ACL (access lists) set for this file. When we looking at them, we can see

```
getfacl index.php

# file: index.php
# owner: sntecard
# group: sntecard
user::rw-
user:cyberuser:rwx              #effective:rw-
group::r--
mask::rw-
other::rw-
```

Which means NO group write access. Change this by

```
setfacl -m group::rw- index.php
```

solves an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `id` to see what your current user and group id's are. Effectively you should log in again to pick up your new group id.

> P.S. What is that "+" at the end of rights line actually means?

This is hidden in the info pages (info ls)

> ```
> Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
>  whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
>  applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
>  bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is
>  a printing character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>  security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>  marked with a `+' character.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In the output of the `ls -ls` :

```
 8 -rw-r--r--+ 1 sntecard  sntecard    4669 Sep 18 12:34 index.php
```

The number `8` is the result of the `-s` option and the size of the file in blocks.

The `-rw-r--r--+` are in order the human readable permissions for the user who owns it (`-rw`), other users in the file’s group (`-r-`), other users not in the file’s group (`-r-`), or all users (`-`).

The trailing `+` is an indication of more extended access controls. Those can't be displayed by `ls` and require helper commands. In case of file-systems mounted with the acl option for instance `getfacl` to display and `setfacl` to modify POSIX ACL's.

POSIX ACL's will override the simple `ugoa` permissions used by `chmod` and `chown`.

If instead of the trailing plus `+` a dot `.` would have been displayed; that indicates SELinux context, requiring the `-Z` flag in `ls` to display them.

For completeness, `1` is the reference count, which would be `2` if there was a hardlink to the file and 3 for two hardlinks, etc. For a directory that number is at least two, and increased with each file and/or directory in that directory.

Then owner and the group, followed by the actual file-size in bytes. A directory with size `0` is one not holding any files, such as pseudo file-systems like /proc, /sys and those managed by the automounter by the way. Than the time stamp of the last modification date followed by the actual filename.